# Devise logout if 2 Rails apps running local

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have fully functional Rails 4 apps that run fine separately on the same MBPro, but if I have both running at the same time with a user logged into both, the last one where a user logs in, causes the other app's logged in user session to expire and I'm back at the login screen for that app.  I am using Devise.

The rails start command I am using is:

`rails s -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.0`
`rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Take a look at a couple of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386624/rails-how-to-use-an-in-memory-sessionstore) , they may help you

Comment: @Hayden this no longer works. I also noticed in Rails docs it is :mem_cache_store not :cache_store.  I'm on Rails 4.2.10 for these apps. Thx Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hayden's answer in the above comment didn't it. Notice the fix in the comment below.

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cache_store
```

Comment: The real fix is I noticed I was using the same session cookie name for both apps, but overwriting each other.  I resolved by adding an identifier in front the cookie name  in <your app>/config/initializers/session_store.rb `Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, { :key =>           '_ping_session',`